# Android - Setting X and Y coordinates to view in runtime

Tags: android, layout, view, coordinates, parameters

I have my own created class that extends class View.
I need to set the X and Y coordinates and add my view in runtime.

adding it is OK. My question is:

Is there a way to set X and Y without the use of **AbsoluteLayout** params?

(I didn't found any other options of setX/setY in other layout params).

Thanks in Advance,
Amigal

Comment: what are you setting the x and y value of? if you draw an object at a certain x,y coordinate pair and then save those values. then if you want to set the values of a new x and y pair then you could redraw it at a new x,y pair.  Your coordinates will also change dependent upon different width and heights of phones so you have to take that in consideration.